# How do the Ethers in Ethereum Wallet increase?

Tags: contract-development, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have created a private test net and an account in Ethereum Wallet by referring this link: https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html

I have ethers in the etherbase account as well. I have deployed one smart contract and everything seems to work fine. The only concern that I have is how the ethers in the base account keep on increasing on their own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (a) node is mining in a low-competition environment. The rewards go to the etherbase address.

Hope it helps.